# How to include jQuery CDN in Webpack?

Tags: jquery, webpack, cdn

Since a CDN version of jQuery is very likely to be cached. Is there a way to include the CDN version in webpack as opposed to the local npm version.

What is the best way to include jQuery in Webpack if it's not loaded on the page?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? *"You can also use the `externals` option to import an existing API into applications. For example, if you want to use jQuery from a CDN via a separate `<script>` tag while still explicitly declaring it as a dependency via `require("jquery")`, you would specify it as external like so: `{ externals: { jquery: "jQuery" } }`."* https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html

Comment: Yeah. But what if the page doesn't have jquery <script>? How do I include such a line in the bundle, preferably the CDN version?

Comment: Can you not edit the HTML file and add the tag?

Comment: I'm building an embed.js for any website so the answer is no I can't.

Comment: Then you might want what is proposed in  https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/240  (which I found through https://www.google.com/search?q=webpack+cdn+loader).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Can you put into an answer?

Comment: Not a dupe. This is about proactively loading external libs on webpages, not just importing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to have been discussed before, see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150. The response was:

> webpack is a module bundler not a javascript loader. It package files
>   from local disk and don't load files from the web (except its own
>   chunks).
>
> Use a javascript loader, i. e. [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js)
>
> ```
> var $script = require("scriptjs");
> $script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js", function() {
>     // ... 
> });
> ```