# How to load JS library in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use MathQuill editor in my project.

I try to load js library

```
import 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery!jquery'
import 'expose-loader?m!expose-loader?MathQuill!../assets/mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill'
import("../assets/mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill.css")
```

but when I get call

```
MathQuill.getInterface(2);
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInterface' of undefined

In the console I see that MathQuill module is empty:

```
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
__proto__: Object
```

How can I load a JS library in Vue?

Comment: did you try `import MathQuill from 'expose-loader?m!expose-loader?MathQuill!../assets/mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill'`  ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584154/how-to-include-external-libraries-via-cdn-asynchronously-in-webpack

Comment: Yes, I  do. jQuery loads ok, but MathQuill not